# Indoor Cat Sneaking Outside, Urinating on Deck BBQ Cover

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, outdoor

I have an old cat (16+ yr) who has figured out how to tailgate the dogs out the dog-door (the door is self-locking door which to dogs can open via a dongle on their collar). This does not bother us too much, since our back yard is fenced and he does not jump it. However, he has gotten into the habit of peeing on BBQ cover on our deck -- just outside the kitchen door.

The deck is a tile floor deck with plastic drainage, so the urine drips off the cover and can soak into the tile or it just falls through and sits in the plastic trough -- stinking up the deck, the kitchen and not making using the BBQ (or just sitting around the deck) particularly enjoyable.

We've used several pet cleaning products to eliminate the smells, but have not found one that discourages him from going back. We'd stop him from going out it possible, but have not figured out how to do this without hindering the dogs' ability to use their door.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we might better discourage the cat from urinating on the BBQ cover, when he has snuck outside?

Comment: How well does he use the litter tray (if you locked the dog door completely for 24 hours would he pee in the litter or somewhere else in the house?). Sometimes they can develop an aversion to the litter box and find somewhere else to go, that may be the case here.

Comment: He does fine with the litter box. I've observed him using it several times in just the last week. I'm not sure if he is just getting outside and then wants to urinate, or trying to get outside to do so.

Comment: Is he neutered?

Comment: Yes. Has been since I got him as a kitten.

Comment: Put a tray of non-clumping sand or dirt out there for him to use instead of the cover.

Comment: "burning" + "urine": maybe he's trying to say he has gonorrhea (ok, bad joke).  Is the cover just sitting on the ground when he pees on it (if so can you move it somewhere out of reach) or is it that he jumps on top of the grill?

Comment: The cover is covering the grill, he is on the deck/ground peeing up onto it - such as a wall.

Comment: That is spraying.  This is probably a response to other cats doing the same thing on his turf.  You could try cleaning the cover and the grill, and using means to make the deck an annoying place for neighbor cats.

Answer (score 2):

Given his age, your three basic options are:

1. Stop the cat from going outside, or at least stop him from tailgating after the dogs unless he has used the indoor litter tray, which I am assuming you have. Probably easier said than done in your instance.
2. Stop the cat from going on the BBQ cover. You say you have already tried this, so this can be discounted in your instance as well.
3. Adapt to the cat's new pattern, and move things such that there is a more appropriate item in that location, one which the cat can learn to use and be happy with. I don't know whether moving the barbecue is a practicable option in your case, but it should give you a different angle from which to view the problem.